# Plotting points on a psp object based on distance

Tags: r, plot, line, spatstat

I have a distance sequence, which I would like to plot of a line in spatstat. Example:

```
library(spatstat)

x <- c(0.3, 5)
y <- c(3, 1.2)

range.x <- c(0, max(x)+0.2)
range.y <- c(0, max(y)+0.2)

owin <- owin(range.x, range.y)
the.line <- psp(x0 = x[1],x1 = x[2],y0 = y[1],y1 = y[2], window = owin)

plot(the.line)    

seqs <- data.frame(name = seq(1,7), distance = c(0.12, 0.3, 0.45, 0.5, 0.7, 0.89, 0.95))
lengths <- seqs$distance*lengths.psp(the.line)
```

I would like to plot `lengths` on top of `the.line` using `seqs$name` as labels in a following way (labels added with Illustrator):

[image]

Would anyone know how to do this? Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` function will allow you to add text to an existing plot.  Whether you can rotate the text or not depends on the graphics device that you are using, see `?par` sections on 'crt' and 'srt'.  Also see the 'adj' argument to `text` for how to get the text above the line rather than obscuring the line.

This all assumes that the plotting is being done in base graphics.

The following worked for me on windows (using the default windows graphics device) after running the code above:

```
x.new <- seqs$distance*x[2] + (1-seqs$distance)*x[1]
y.new <- seqs$distance*y[2] + (1-seqs$distance)*y[1]

tmp.x <- grconvertX(x, to='inches')
tmp.y <- grconvertY(y, to='inches')
theta <- atan2(diff(tmp.y),diff(tmp.x))*180/pi

text( x.new, y.new, seqs$name, adj=c(0,0), srt=theta )
```

Comment: Well...I have used spatstat to plot and calculate my rather complex data, so the plotting needs to be done on spatstat window (owin). Besides I don't know the coordinates of my text. Only the distance along the line.

Comment: I just ran your code above (through the plot), then used the 'locator' function and clicked on the ends of the line and the results matched with your 'x' and 'y' variable (with a little error from my clicking), so it looks like the plot is in base graphics and does not do anything fancy with the coordinates.  Finding the coordinates given x and y and the distance along the line is algebra, finding the correct angle is algebra and trig, then just use the text function as above.